# Inline asp.net code, list of events I can override

Tags: asp.net, inline-code

In my inline .aspx page, I want to override the pre-init event.

How can I do this?

is it:

```
void pre_init(object sender)
```

?

**Update**
This is a user control

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Comment: OnPreInit(object, System.EventArgs)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: It sounds like you're in an asCx control rather than an asPx page.  If this is true, try the OnInit() method instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your page you can start typing "protected override", hit enter or tab to complete, hit space, and intellisense will give a list of all the stuff you can override.  If you pick one from the list it will generate the

```
base.myOverriddenMethod(e);
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for an overview of the page life cycle and a description of all events you can handle.